# How to switch between three items in array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am making a language switcher in Next.js. Basically there are three languages and clicked language should setToActive should be placed to previous active language and previous language should be placed the place of new active. I am setting active language but moving previous active language to the place of secondary or tertiary place is problem. Any suggestion is very appreciated.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { IoMdArrowDropup, IoMdArrowDropdown } from "react-icons/io";
import { AiOutlineCheck } from "react-icons/ai";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

const LanguageSwitcher = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const locales = router.locales;
  const [showLG, setshowLG] = useState(false);
  const [lan, setLan] = useState(locales[0]);

  console.log("english");

  return (
    <div className="z-50">
      <div
        onClick={() => setshowLG(!showLG)}
        className="w-16 p-4 bg-white text-sm font-medium leading-none text-gray-800 flex items-center justify-between cursor-pointer"
      >
        {lan.toUpperCase()}
        <div>
          {showLG ? (
            <div className="p-6">
              <IoMdArrowDropup size="15" />
            </div>
          ) : (
            <div>
              <IoMdArrowDropdown size="15" />
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
      {showLG && (
        <div className="w-16 mt-2 p-4 bg-white shadow rounded absolute top-11">
          <p
            onClick={() =>
              setLan(locales[1)
            }
            className="text-sm leading-normal  text-gray-800"
          >
            {locales[1}
          </p>
          <p
            onClick={() => setLan(locales[2])}
            className="text-sm leading-normal mt-4 text-gray-800"
          >
            {locales[2]}
          </p>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
export default LanguageSwitcher;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you track the current locale index in a state variable rather than tracking the actual locale itself. You can then create a helper function that always returns a value between `0` and `2` (see `getLangIndex`), and increase the index when selecting a new value.

```js
const LanguageSwitcher = () => {
    const router = useRouter();
    const locales = router.locales;
    const [showLG, setShowLG] = useState(false);
    const [lan, setLan] = useState(0);

    const getLangIndex = (index) => index % locales.length;

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => setShowLG(!showLG)}>{locales[lan].toUpperCase()}</button>
            {showLG && (
                <div>
                    <p onClick={() => setLan((i) => getLangIndex(i + 1))}>
                        {locales[getLangIndex(lan + 1)]}
                    </p>
                    <p onClick={() => setLan((i) => getLangIndex(i + 2))}>
                        {locales[getLangIndex(lan + 2)]}
                    </p>
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};
```

You also have a few typos in the code you shared that make it un-runnable. Make sure to also correct those.

Comment: Hi juliomalves, there is no "i" where are you getting it?

Comment: That's using the function format when calling `setLan` to update the state variable, it refers to the current value of `lan`. See https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous. It's similar to doing `setLan(getLangIndex(lan + 1))`, but it ensures we're getting the right value for `lan`.

Comment: have you tested it?

Comment: @DilshodSh Yes, I have. Here's a codesandbox example with the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/nextjs-language-switcher-vnvkq4.

Answer (score 0):

Untested but should work

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { IoMdArrowDropup, IoMdArrowDropdown } from "react-icons/io";
import { AiOutlineCheck } from "react-icons/ai";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

const LanguageSwitcher = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const locales = router.locales;
  const [showLG, setshowLG] = useState(false);
  const [lan, setLan] = useState(0); // use index instead

  const getLanIndex = offset => {
    return (lan + offset + locales.length) % locales.length;
  }

  console.log("english");

  return (
    <div className="z-50">
      <div
        onClick={() => setshowLG(!showLG)}
        className="w-16 p-4 bg-white text-sm font-medium leading-none text-gray-800 flex items-center justify-between cursor-pointer"
      >
        {locales[lan].toUpperCase()}
        <div>
          {showLG ? (
            <div className="p-6">
              <IoMdArrowDropup size="15" />
            </div>
          ) : (
            <div>
              <IoMdArrowDropdown size="15" />
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
      {showLG && (
        <div className="w-16 mt-2 p-4 bg-white shadow rounded absolute top-11">
          <p
            onClick={() =>
              setLan(getLanIndex(-1))
            }
            className="text-sm leading-normal  text-gray-800"
          >
            {locales[getLanIndex(-1)}
          </p>
          <p
            onClick={() => setLan(getLanIndex(+1))}
            className="text-sm leading-normal mt-4 text-gray-800"
          >
            {locales[getLanIndex(-1)}
          </p>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
export default LanguageSwitcher;
```

Comment: Hi! I have just tested it there are two problems, first its getting fourth presudo language which is not necessary, second its getting two same language like en , en or ru, ru so I changed getLanIndex function to this (lan + offset + locales.length - 1) % locales.length; now only problem is its getting two same language

Comment: I have made some logic and its working but it looks terrible

Comment: I probably made a math mistake somewhere as I didn't test the code.

Comment: I did not understand the logic behind your code